# How to I make gerrit query that spans across few specific projects?

Tags: regex, gerrit

I tried for few hours to find the right syntax for making a regex query that returns reviews from 2-3 different projects but I failed and decided to crowdsource the task ;)

The search is documented at https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/user-search.html and mentions possible use of REGEX,... but it just didn't work.

Task: return all CRs from `openstack-infra/gerritlib` and `openstack-infra/git-review` projects from https://review.openstack.org

Doing it for one project works well `project:openstack-infra/gerritlib`

Ideally I would like to look for somethign like `^openstack-infra\/(gerritlib|git-review)`, or at least this is the standard regex syntax.

Still, I found impossible to use parentheses so far, every time I used them it stopped it from returning any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You don't need to escape the "/" character.

2) You need to use double quotes to make the parentheses work.

So the following search should work for you:

```
project:"^openstack-infra/(gerritlib|git-review)"
```

Comment: The problem was that the documentation used single quotes as example but gerrit supported only double quotes. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=9449 and my CR to fix it.